# Custom ReCaptcha not displaying on page load in chrome. Link provided

Tags: css, google-chrome, recaptcha

The ReCaptcha widget on a page I'm working on (http://ec2-174-129-62-227.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8111/password-recovery-page.html) is not displaying when the page is loaded.

For some reason, I can get it to load consistently if I:

1. mouseover the 'recover password' button
2. change any style via chrome's web inspector

I have this same custom recaptcha widget on several other pages, but I have absolutely no issue with them.

I also couldn't find any "display: none", "height: 0", "visibility: hidden" styling or anything of the sort via chrome's web inspector when the widget isn't displaying. However, I did notice that, even though the widget isn't displaying, it has already loaded a jumbled word image for the captcha.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I just want to say that although I can duplicate the problem, mousing over the login button does nothing. The words are only shown after a reload (F5 or Ctrl+R).

Comment: Try moving the `<script>` and `<noscript>` tags out of `<form>`

Comment: @PiLHA Phew! That did it. Do you want to put that in the form of an answer?

Comment: @dom No need, I already feel useful to have helped.